# Selecting column names in mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql, select

Adding some php/mysql database queries to a site, and not sure how to structure this one.

The table looks like:

```
memberid    1111    1112    1119    1349    1350...
1           1       1       0       0       0
2           0       1       1       0       0
3           1       1       0       0       1
...
```

The column names (1111 etc.) are video id's, and the the zero's and ones represent whether that member has that video in their queue or not.

My query needs to look at one member, and see which videos are in their queue.

I'm intending for my code to look somewhat like:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT column names FROM queue WHERE memberid = $memberid AND its value = 1", $connection);
if (!$data) {
    die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
}

while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
    $list[] = $result['columnnames'];
}
```

Help! Thanks.
-Daniel

Comment: Your column names are ids of other entires in the database? So you're adding a new column for every new video? Please be aware that that is a total database structure normalization fail.

Comment: I think I would write death threats to the developer if I ever had to maintain this program. Total SQL fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you have a column for every video?

Member:

```
CREATE TABLE member (
    member_id INT PRIMARY_KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100)
);
```

Video:

```
CREATE TABLE video (
   video_id INT PRIMARY_KEY,
   title VARCHAR(150)
);
```

MemberQueue:

```
CREATE TABLE memberqueue (
    member_id INT,
    video_id INT
);
```

Get a members videos in their queue:

```
SELECT video.video_id, video.title
FROM member
JOIN memberqueue
    ON member.member_id = memberqueue.member_id
JOIN video
    ON memberqueue.video_id = video.video_id
WHERE member.member_id = $member_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work,

```
SELECT if (`1111`=1 then `1111` else NULL) as `1111`, if (`2222`=1 then `2222` else NULL) as `2222` ... 
FROM queue
WHERE memberid = $memberid
```

I haven't tested this so it might take some playing.  Also there are alot better ways to deal with something like this.  What do you do when you add a new video?  Add new database column?

Have you thought about having one column and storing the video as a bit.  Then keeping a mapping for bits to videos.

```
eg.
member_id       videos
1               1010
2               0110

videos table
video_id        bit
1               1000
2               0100
3               0010
4               0001
```

now you can select the value of videos usign the member id.  and use bitwise operations to figure out which videos are in their queue.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if you *really* want to get the column names, here is how to do it:

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema = 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME' 
AND table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME';
```

Of course that means your MySQL user would need `SELECT` privileges for `information_schema`.